# How to Clear a OnScroll(AbsListView) - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I have a onScrollListener that calls an AsyncTask once the last View in the ListView is shown. The AsyncTask adds Data to a ListView using an ArrayAdapter. The problem is when I clear the ArrayAdapter with `arrayAdapter.clear()` it clears the adapter but all the variables in AbsListView still think the Items exist so it doesn't detect when I am at the bottom of the ListView, Here is the onScrollListener.

```
class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {
                private int visibleThreshold = 5;
                private boolean loading = true;

                public EndlessScrollListener() {
                }
                public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
                    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


                   if (loading) {
                        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                           loading = false;
                            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                        }
                }
                    if (!loading && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount) {

                        new loadComments().execute();
                        loading = true;
                    }




                }

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                } 
            }
```

How Can I also reset the variables in AbsListView so it understand the when I have reached the bottom of the listView?

Answer (score 0):

After calling `clear()` on your `Adapter`, you must call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Here is the snippet from the API:

> public void **notifyDataSetChanged()**
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: I do call that and it does the same thing.

Comment: Hmm you should put that in your question. We can't see what your AsyncTask does.